# Divvying people into rooms by last name?

Tags: algorithm

I often teach large introductory programming classes (400 - 600 students) and when exam time comes around, we often have to split the class up into different rooms in order to make sure everyone has a seat for the exam.

To keep things logistically simple, I usually break the class apart by last name.  For example, I might send students with last names A - H to one room, last name I - L to a second room, M - S to a third room, and T - Z to a fourth room.

The challenge in doing this is that the rooms often have wildly different capacities and it can be hard to find a way to segment the class in a way that causes everyone to fit.  For example, suppose that the distribution of last names is (for simplicity) the following:

- Last name starts with A: 25
- Last name starts with B: 150
- Last name starts with C: 200
- Last name starts with D: 50

Suppose that I have rooms with capacities 350, 50, and 50.  A greedy algorithm for finding a room assignment might be to sort the rooms into descending order of capacity, then try to fill in the rooms in that order.  This, unfortunately, doesn't always work.  For example, in this case, the right option is to put last name A in one room of size 50, last names B - C into the room of size 350, and last name D into another room of size 50.  The greedy algorithm would put last names A and B into the 350-person room, then fail to find seats for everyone else.

It's easy to solve this problem by just trying all possible permutations of the room orderings and then running the greedy algorithm on each ordering.  This will either find an assignment that works or report that none exists.  However, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, given that the number of rooms might be between 10 and 20 and checking all permutations might not be feasible.

To summarize, the formal problem statement is the following:

> You are given a frequency histogram of the last names of the students in a class, along with a list of rooms and their capacities.  Your goal is to divvy up the students by the first letter of their last name so that each room is assigned a contiguous block of letters and does not exceed its capacity.

Is there an efficient algorithm for this, or at least one that is efficient for reasonable room sizes?

**EDIT:** Many people have asked about the contiguous condition.  The rules are

- Each room should be assigned at most a block of contiguous letters, and
- No letter should be assigned to two or more rooms.

For example, you could not put A - E, H - N, and P - Z into the same room.  You could also not put A - C in one room and B - D in another.

Thanks!

Comment: can you divide students whose last name starts with a same character in two different rooms?

Comment: @Bill- For the sake of this problem, let's say no.  Logistically, it would be really bad if we had multiple rooms for the same letter and everyone showed up to just one of them.

Comment: You don't need to split on a single letter.

Comment: Sound like a bin packing problem http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: @starblue- Yes, that's true.  I'm making a somewhat restrictive assumption here in the interests of simplicity (and making the question interesting to solve.)

Comment: @JasonSperske- Definitely.  This problem is a little different from a conventional bin packing problem in that the elements have to be allocated in blocks, rather than individually.

Comment: Is wrap around allowed (Z->A)?

Comment: Why not do this completely randomly, take the students' full names and call a hashing function on them, modulo 8. If the answer is equivalent to 0-5, use Room A.  If the answer is 6, use room B, and if 7, use Room C.

Comment: @nhahtdh- For simplicity, let's say that this isn't allowed.  I'm hoping to find a very simple allocation scheme, and wrapping around is likely to be confusing.

Comment: @EricJablow- I'm hoping to have the simplest scheme I can for assigning people to rooms.  If everything is broken apart into blocks of people, then it's really easy for students to determine where they need to be.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Is it OK if I suggest a non-optimal greedy solution?

Comment: @nhahtdh- The algorithm has to be guaranteed to find a solution if one exists, but it doesn't need to do so in the most elegant way.  If you have a greedy solution that will always find a solution if there is one, please feel free to post it!

Comment: @templatetypedef You teach a *single* class that has between 400 and 600 students? Forgive me for saying this, but I'd hardly call that "teaching". I taught classes with 40 people and it was difficult... can't even imagine 400.

Comment: Just to clarify: Given this example A = 50, B = 120, C = 200, D = 100, and 2 classrooms with capacity 320, 200, how many solution can you think of?

Comment: @nhahtdh- There would be just one solution there (A - B in one room, C - D in another).  It's absolutely the case that if we rearranged people arbitrarily we could get another solution, but under the restrictions of contiguous blocks only the one solution is legal.

Comment: Would be a lot easier to just assign each student a sequential number.  Students m through n in room A, o through p in room B, etc.  But then you wouldn't get to spend time writing code to do it.  :)

Comment: Are the student groups in one room must be contiguous?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Can you clarify about the contiguous block condition? It seems that there are a number of misunderstanding here.

Comment: but you would have to make concessions for the real world situation when there is spill over. when most with common first letter be in the same room but there might be number of rooms -1 letters that are in 2 rooms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be solved using some sort of DP solution on `[m, 2^n]` space, where `m` is number of letters (26 for english) and `n` is number of rooms. With `m == 26` and `n == 20` it will take about  100 MB of space and ~1 sec of time.
Below is solution I have just implemented in C# (it will successfully compile on C++ and Java too, just several minor changes will be needed):

```cs
int[] GetAssignments(int[] studentsPerLetter, int[] rooms)
{
    int numberOfRooms = rooms.Length;
    int numberOfLetters = studentsPerLetter.Length;
    int roomSets = 1 << numberOfRooms; // 2 ^ (number of rooms)
    int[,] map = new int[numberOfLetters + 1, roomSets];

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfLetters; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < roomSets; j++)
            map[i, j] = -2;

    map[0, 0] = -1; // starting condition

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < roomSets; j++)
            if (map[i, j] > -2)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < numberOfRooms; k++)
                    if ((j & (1 << k)) == 0)
                    {
                        // this room is empty yet.
                        int roomCapacity = rooms[k];
                        int t = i;
                        for (; t < numberOfLetters && roomCapacity >= studentsPerLetter[t]; t++)
                            roomCapacity -= studentsPerLetter[t];

                        // marking next state as good, also specifying index of just occupied room
                        // - it will help to construct solution backwards.
                        map[t, j | (1 << k)] = k;
                    }
            }

    // Constructing solution.
    int[] res = new int[numberOfLetters];
    int lastIndex = numberOfLetters - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < roomSets; j++)
    {
        int roomMask = j;
        while (map[lastIndex + 1, roomMask] > -1)
        {
            int lastRoom = map[lastIndex + 1, roomMask];
            int roomCapacity = rooms[lastRoom];
            for (; lastIndex >= 0 && roomCapacity >= studentsPerLetter[lastIndex]; lastIndex--)
            {
                res[lastIndex] = lastRoom;
                roomCapacity -= studentsPerLetter[lastIndex];
            }

            roomMask ^= 1 << lastRoom; // Remove last room from set.

            j = roomSets; // Over outer loop.
        }
    }

    return lastIndex > -1 ? null : res;
}
```

Example from OP question:

```
int[] studentsPerLetter = { 25, 150, 200, 50 };
int[] rooms = { 350, 50, 50 };
int[] ans = GetAssignments(studentsPerLetter, rooms);
```

Answer will be:

```
2
0
0
1
```

Which indicates index of room for each of the student's last name letter. If assignment is not possible my solution will return `null`.

---

**[Edit]**

After thousands of auto generated tests my friend has found a bug in code which constructs solution backwards. It does not influence main algo, so fixing this bug will be an exercise to the reader.

The test case that reveals the bug is `students = [13,75,21,49,3,12,27,7]` and `rooms = [6,82,89,6,56]`. My solution return no answers, but actually there is an answer. Please note that first part of solution works properly, but answer construction part fails.

Comment: I think this looks more like a solution. The correctness depends on whether putting the maximum number of student in a room will make we miss a solution, which I think is **not** the case, but I can't think of a proof.

Comment: As for me - proof seems to be intuitive and trivial, however to define it mathematically correct can be difficult for me. If you just concerned about this one aspect of solution - than you can just slightly modify solution and check 'not-full-loads' also. Just move `map[t, j | (1 << k)] = k;` line inside the loop above it. It will not change main idea of the solution and its theorethical complexity.

Comment: Can you share the test case which it fails?

Comment: @nhahtdh - test case: students=[13,75,21,49,3,12,27,7] rooms=[6,82,89,6,56]. My solution return no answers, but actually there is an answer. Please note that first part of solution works properly, but answer construction part fails.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is `NP-Complete` and thus there is no known `polynomial` time (aka efficient) solution for this (as long as people cannot prove `P = NP`). You can reduce an instance of knapsack or bin-packing problem to your problem to prove it is `NP-complete`.

To solve this you can use 0-1 knapsack problem. Here is how:
First pick the biggest classroom size and try to allocate as many group of students you can (using 0-1 knapsack), i.e equal to the size of the room. You are guaranteed not to split a group of student, as this is 0-1 knapsack. Once done, take the next biggest classroom  and continue.

(You use any known heuristic to solve 0-1 knapsack problem.)

Here is the reduction --
You need to reduce a general instance of 0-1 knapsack to a specific instance of your problem.
So lets take a general instance of 0-1 knapsack. Lets take a sack whose weight is `W` and you have `x_1, x_2, ... x_n` groups and their corresponding weights are `w_1, w_2, ... w_n`.

Now the reduction --- this general instance is reduced to your problem as follows:
you have one classroom with seating capacity `W`. Each `x_i (i \in (1,n))` is a group of students whose last alphabet begins with `i` and their number (aka size of group) is `w_i`.

Now you can prove if there is a solution of 0-1 knapsack problem, your problem has a solution...and the converse....also if there is no solution for 0-1 knapsack, then your problem have no solution, and vice versa.

Please remember the important thing of reduction -- general instance of a known `NP-C` problem to a specific instance of your problem.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `as many group of students you can` What is the "value" here? If "value" is the number of groups, then you may risk not fitting the largest group for the smaller classes.

Comment: the value is same as the size of the class which you are considering for this iteration of the 0-1 knapsack problem

Comment: If it is the size of the class, then how would you consider between 2 ways of grouping with the same total size? Another thing: the groups must be contiguous.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate your questions. If there are 2 ways, you just pick one way and continue. Basically you are solving 0-1 knapsack for each classroom size.

Comment: However you are not guaranteed sorted order of last names in the classroom, you may end up a room with "A" + "C", another "D" +"Z" +"S". Basically, whatever is the solution for knapsack for the classroom you are solving.

Comment: Can you explain how the reduction works?  Remember that to show that this is NP-complete, you have to show how to solve 0-1 knapsack using a black-box solver for this problem, rather than the other way around.

Comment: How will your algorithm solves A = 50, B = 100, C = 200, D = 100, and 2 classrooms with capacity 300, 200? Note that you can't just arbitrarily pick any.

Comment: "You can reduce this problem to an instance of knapsack or bin-packing problem to prove it is NP-complete" - this is wrong.

To prove NP-completeness, you have to reduce known NP-complete problem to the problem in question, not the other way around.

Comment: "Please remember the important thing of reduction -- general instance of a known NP-C problem to a specific instance of your problem." -- from my answer....and updated the first paragraph where I had it othe way round...Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Bill- I'm not sure I see how the reduction works.  My question is whether it's possible to divvy everyone up at all.  Your original starting knapsack problem asks what the maximum number of objects you can pack into the knapsack is.  Why is it the case that you can fit everyone into a single room of capacity W iff you can get exactly W weight out of your original set of objects?

Comment: I think 0-1 Knapsack is not applicable here, since you need to assign contiguous blocks of student's name. Let's say you found a way to make it work, the optimal way to pack students into one class doesn't mean that the overall solution is correct. For example: A = 50, B = **120**, C = 200, D = 100, and 2 classrooms with capacity **320**, 200. You will end up grouping B and C into 320 cap class, and fails.

Comment: Since the problem of finding a sub-group of students for a clasroom is NP-C, the more general problem which involves multiple classrooms remains NP-C.

Comment: @nhahtdh --- All I am saying is to use a known heuristic to solve the 0-1 knapsack problem for each classroom.

Comment: @Bill: How are you going to combine it? Your answer doesn't contain the actual algorithm, but only talks about the NP-Completeness. And note that finding the solution to this problem, where a contiguous region is needed is not even NP-C, it is just Polynomial.

Comment: @nhahtdh -- start with the biggest classroom and continue. But your assumption of grouping B and C may not always be true. It depends on how you solve the knapsack. Moreover, in your example, if you group B+C in 320 seat classroom, what is wrong in putting A+D in 200 seat classroom?

Comment: I am going to downvote this, since the algorithm is not clear at all. Just take the A = 50, B = 120, C = 200, D = 100, and 2 classrooms with capacity 320, 200 example, and you are going to fail.

Comment: @nhahtdh  How does it fail?? You can always downvote, it is your own choice :)

Comment: @bill: Show me how it can succeed? Your algorithm must at least pass a simple test case.

Comment: "Moreover, in your example, if you group B+C in 320 seat classroom, what is wrong in putting A+D in 200 seat classroom?" -- from my previous comment.

Comment: @Bill: It is just wrong. Since A and D are not contiguous. Check the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh Sorry, you have a wrong understanding of the question. Please see my 4th comment... "However you are not guaranteed sorted order of last names in the classroom, you may end up a room with "A" + "C", another "D" +"Z" +"S". Basically, whatever is the solution for knapsack for the classroom you are solving. –"

Comment: @nhahtdh Here "contiguous" means you can not split people with "A" in different rooms. That is my understanding.

Comment: @Bill: `contiguous block of letters` - check the question again. It must be A-D or B-C, if you take out something in between, it is no longer contiguous.

Comment: @templatetypedef --- can you please clarify this to `nhahtdh`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that should work reasonably well, given common assumptions about the distribution of last names by initial. Fill the rooms from smallest capacity to largest as compactly as possible within the constraints, with no backtracking.

It seems reasonable (to me at least) for the largest room to be listed last, as being for "everyone else" not already listed.

Comment: How are you going to ensure the contiguous block of names condition?

Comment: Is the OP's intent to solve a real problem reasonably (ie without allowing it to become NP), or is it to reword a well-known NP problem in a slightly different form? I am interpreting his intent as (1), and it seems that the responders are trying to drag him into (2). Only OP can provide the definitive interpretation of what is required.

Comment: In other words, by exploring a slightly simpler problem, where contiguous name selection is relaxed for the room of largest capacity, a real-world solution might be both easier to code and more performant.

Comment: From his reply to my comment, it seems that he wants a solution if there is a solution. So I think he wants to solve the problem **given the constraints that he has** (not the general problem), in reasonable time, without sacrificing the accuracy. There are many problems which are NP, but with small size, there are solutions more efficient than brute force approach.

Comment: I am a physicist by training. In physics, one is taught that when a problem gets too difficult, explore simplifications of it that retain its original spirit.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to make life so complicated? Why cann't you assign registration numbers to each student and then use the number to allocate them whatever the way you want :) You do not need to write a code, students are happy, everyone is happy.

Comment: (This answer is probably best written as a comment).  This would absolutely work, but I'm interested in solving this particular problem both as an algorithmically interesting exercise and because it provides an extremely simple system that students can easily use to determine their room numbers.  There is no need to prepare a large table for students to look at.